# PHPStan has Symfony version discrepancy using composer

Tags: symfony, phpstan

So, it's been a while since i started to get this error in my PHPStan report, on my Gitlab CI as well as my local machine.

[image: PHPStan error]

Checking my Symfony foundation package within `composer show` tells me i'm using v4.3.1

[image]

But if you check the [matching Symfony repo](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/4.3/HeaderBag.php#L110) you see that this method actually takes 3 args. Checking the file on my local system logically shows the same line.

[image: HeaderBag::get]

So, i'm wondering: how can PHPStan see only 2 arguments when there's actually 3? From v4.4 the method actually uses only 2, but not in my case.

Any suggestion that doesn't involve updating to 4.4?

Comment: The real question si why PHPStan raises this warning. It shouldn't. Can you check if you  have another version of the `http-foundation` somewhere in the dependencies? Can you run `composer why symfony/http-foundation`?

Comment: You should check the associated `vendor` directory with your project, you should find HeaderBag::get() with 2 parameters. It's also possible that you run PHPStan in some weird way, for example installed globally with Composer in your OS, and you also installed different version of Symfony also globally in your OS, and PHPStan sees that instead.

Comment: Also, please open an issue in PHPStan GitHub repo next time instead :)

Comment: I'll check for a global something tomorrow, thanks Ondrej. I didn't want to bother you in your issues with a most likely non-related issue 

Comment: I treat issues as a support forum too :) https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/new/choose

Comment: Can you share the matching call from `Helper/RequestHelper`?